# Window start position overlapping with Menubar and Titlebar since last update

Tags: unity, virtualbox, compiz, window

I am running Ubungu 16.04 on virtualbox. Till today everything worked fine. But at morning I got some news about update and I did it and had to restart the VM because the Updater wanted me to.

Since that I had several problems:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD</kbd> did not position windows in grid anymore (Solved with compizconfig-settings-manager)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ARROWKEY</kbd> did not switch workspaces (Also solved with compizconfig-settings-manager)

Now one problem is left:

When I open new applications, for example a Terminal, it is located on the upper left position of the Screen. But behind the Unity Menubar and the upper title bar. It is totally not easy to drag and drop it down because the Window is hidden by the titlebar.

Now after my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys are working again it is better to handle, but it is still annoying problem.

Does anybody have idea what happened during this update at morning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On compizconfig-settings-manager. Just enable **Place Windows** on *Windows Management* category.

Comment: thanks, but any workaround without any new manager ?

Answer (score 0):

First, install `compizconfig-settings-manager`

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then search **compizconfig-settings-manager** from search panel

[image]

Now scroll down to the opened to the compizconfig window and go to the Window Management

[image]

Enable **Place Windows**